# Error in When... Then : Before Update Trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I have a table named `medical_folder` with 2 columns named `id_med_folder` and `cure`, which are the id of the patient and the cure.

I need to make a trigger that updates the `cure` column,
so I made a 2nd table named `audit` with columns `EMP_ID` and `EMP_CURE`.

Then, through a trigger I execute a function named `auditfunc()`.

However, when I try to pass the `NEW.ID` and `NEW.CURE` I get an error that I can't understand.

```
    CREATE TABLE AUDIT(
    EMP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    EMP_CURE TEXT NOT NULL
);


CREATE TRIGGER LeTrigger 
AFTER UPDATE ON medical_folder
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE auditfunc();



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditfunc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$LeTrigger$
DECLARE 
    aidi integer Not null;
    kiour text Not null;
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO AUDIT(EMP_ID,EMP_CURE)
    VALUES(NEW.ID, NEW.CURE);
    aidi = New.ID;
    kiour = New.Cure;   
    RETURN NEW;
    WHEN medical_folder.id_med_folder = aidi THEN medical_folder.cure = kiour   
END;
$LeTrigger$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code; it's not searchable and we can't copy/paste it.

Comment: Are you trying to make a `CASE` statement? If so, you are missing the `CASE`... and can you put the code in text for us?

Comment: @JacobH With When...Then i try to find the id_med_folder that is equal to EMP_ID and change cure

Comment: For example if Emp_ID = 76 and EMP_CURE = 'Flue' then i have to find the id_med_folder = 76 and change its medical_folder.cure to 'Flue'

Comment: I'm not familiar with using CASE in a posgresql insert statement. But you definitely are missing the CASE part. I would look at the documentation to start.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that `when` clause? Do you only want to fire the trigger when then condition is met? Then the `when` clause needs to be in the `create trigger` statement [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: do you want `IF THEN ELSE END IF` ?..